# Process.Threads does not contain the full list of threads spawned by a process

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, process-explorer

My application starts a secondary Process (an exe file stored in the filesystem). This Process then spawns several Threads that perform long operations multicore.

I can see from ProcessExplorer the list of threads started by this Process:

[image]

In yellow, the Process that my application started, in red the "long" threads that this Process started by itself (note that their addresses starts from a DLL!).

In my C# code, I expect to see all of these threads using [myprocess.Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.threads?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Threads) property (where `myprocess` is the Process started by my app). Instead, I see thread ID 18160 and others, **but not the ones  highlighted in red**. Why?

In general, as you see from the image the total count of threads is 43, while the size of `myprocess.Threads` is 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `Process.Threads` returns all threads associated with this process, but they might be threads that are not necessarily *owned* by this process.

`Process.Threads` uses [CreateToolHelp32Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) to collect the information on Win32.  The documentation of `CreateToolHelp32Snapshot` says:

> To identify the threads that belong to a specific process, compare its
>   process identifier to the th32OwnerProcessID member of the
>   THREADENTRY32 structure when enumerating the threads.

The code that populates `Process.Threads`, however, doesn't check `th32OwnerProcessID`; it simply enumerates all threads.  You can see the code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,0ed5796ac91d4cef):

```
if (NativeMethods.Thread32First(handleRef, thread)) 
{
    do 
    {
       ThreadInfo threadInfo = new ThreadInfo();
       threadInfo.threadId = thread.th32ThreadID;
       threadInfo.processId = thread.th32OwnerProcessID;
       threadInfo.basePriority = thread.tpBasePri;
       threadInfo.currentPriority = thread.tpBasePri + thread.tpDeltaPri;
       threadInfos.Add(threadInfo);
    }
    while (NativeMethods.Thread32Next(handleRef, thread));
}
```

So, I assume you also see threads that are owned by other processes, but associated with your child process.

Comment: Thanks, Thread32First/Thread32Next returns all the threads listed by ProcessExplorer